# fwrite() and fread() parts of a struct into binary file

Tags: c, struct

My binary file is divided into blocks. Now I want to write a struct to my binary file.
If the size of my struct is larger than the size of a block, I'm thinking of splitting the struct into parts, then write each part to a block (Those blocks do not need to be contiguous).

> For example, I divide my binary file into blocks of size 4 bytes. The size of my struct is 9 bytes.
>   Then I split my struct into 3 parts (4 bytes, 4 bytes, and 1 byte). And I'm going to write part 1 (4 bytes) to 1st block, part 2 (4 bytes) to 3rd block, and part 3 (1 byte) to 6th block.

So if I use **fwrite(str , 4 , 1 , file)**, I can write the part 1 to 1st block. But how about the other parts?

Also, if I want to read my struct from my binary file as my struct is split into 3 parts as above. How can I read each part and combine them into a complete struct using fread()?

Is this idea possible?

Comment: Why would you not read and write the whole thing at once?

Comment: Sounds like [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Why do you need to have your file divided into blocks?

Comment: If you need only parts from e.g. `struct a`, then why not create `struct b` that has only the needed parts from `a` allowing you a complete write of `b`. That keeps that (**now "what did I put where" fog**) to a minimum.

Comment: my file is just like a disk, so some data might be added in the 2nd block.

Comment: I would probably write my own `fwrite` replacement function that accepted the full sized struct and broke it down into block sized chunks to actually write to the file.  That way the low level implementation of your "disk" structure is abstracted away from the higher level code that just wants to write huge consecutive chunks to the file.

Answer (score 1):

`unsigned char` is guaranteed to have no padding bits, and it's size is by defintion 1, so a data object of any other type can be copied as `sizeof(the object or the type)` unsigned chars. You can't *compare* two objects as two unsigned char arrays though, because the larger type may have padding (don't care) bits which could differ in the two objects.

Writing:

```
unsigned char *ptr;

ptr = (unsigned char *) &myStruct;
fwrite(ptr, 1, 4, myStream);
ptr += 4;
fwrite(ptr, 1, 4, myStream);
ptr += 4;
fwrite(ptr, 1, 1, myStream);
```

Reading:

```
unsigned char *ptr;

ptr = (unsigned char *) &myStruct;
fread(ptr, 1, 4, myStream);
ptr += 4;
fread(ptr, 1, 4, myStream);
ptr += 4;
fread(ptr, 1, 1, myStream);
```

It's probably a good idea to read/write 4 elements of size 1, instead of 1 object of size 4. The latter could screw up align restrictments, I think.

If you want, skip the ptr variable and cast on-the-fly:

```
fwrite(&myStruct, 1, 4, myStream);
fwrite((unsigned char *) &myStruct + 4, 1, 4, myStream);
fwrite((unsigned char *) &myStruct + 8, 1, 1, myStream);
```

Comment: To add some description to that, 'reinterpret' you structure as a block of bits and then move through it writing chunks of the appropriate size. Managing a large number of arbitrary objects as blocks is a sound idea. Almost all storage systems including operating systems, file systems & databases do this trick. Obviously your chosen block size of 4 bytes is extremely small. 4K (or more...) is a more realistic 'page' size on a modern system.

Comment: So if I read each block to a different variable. For example,
unsigned int ptr1,ptr2,ptr3;
fwrite(&ptr1, 4, 1, myStream);
fwrite(&ptr2, 4, 1, myStream);
fwrite(&ptr3, 1, 1, myStream);

So ptr1 holds data of block 1, ptr2 holds data of block 3, etc. Then how do I combine them into myStruct?